# How do I open a port in Windows 10 for use?

Tags: tcp, udp, windows-10, port

I need to open port#42474 on my Windows 10 system for penetration testing purposes.

I added it to the inbound list of my Windows Defender Firewall (both TCP and UDP protocol), and it is enabled.
However, whenever I am trying to ping this port on my machine using telnet it is throwing an error as

> Connecting To localhost...Could not open connection to the host, on port 42474: Connect failed

I am able to use telnet to ping other sites such as google.com. But not this port on my machine. Below is the command I am running to test the port and the error:

[Port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjOWQ.jpg)
[Telnet error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YiAe.jpg)

```
telnet localhost 42474
```

1. Do I need to do anything else to open port#42474?
2. How do I verify if this port is available for use?

Comment: You need a service to listen on that port if you want to connect to it. If nothing is listening, nothing's going to answer.

Comment: Thank u Mat for the response.Can u suggest me how to do that? I tried assigning a program to the port. But it still did not work.I assigned Google Chrome to that port. But although chrome was opened, When i checked using command netstat -aon, Chrome was operating through other ports and not that port.

Answer (score 0):

TCP ports are bi-directional, so check these tips:

- Verify your service on this port is running: `netstat -a`
- Be sure your firewall isn't blocking (try to deactivate it: if it works well, your rule isn't correct)
- Search for your service log: maybe,
  it receive information, but it's not able to reply. I recommend you to use [PuTTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY) or [Kitty](http://www.9bis.net/kitty/) (which is my favorite, because it's portable without registry keys modification), and try to connect on this port.

If you need a tool that able to listen on the port, see this post: *[Utility to open TCP port to listen state](https://superuser.com/questions/397892/utility-to-open-tcp-port-to-listen-state)* and [netcat](https://joncraton.org/blog/46/netcat-for-windows/).

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [Python programming language](https://www.python.org/). More specifically, the [socket](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html) library:

```
import socket

hote = "localhost"
port = 4444

socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket.connect((hote, port))
print "Connection on {}".format(port)

socket.send(u"Hey my name is Abdx!")

print "Close"
socket.close()
```

Comment: This does not provide anything that Telnet can connect to.